# Number of primes in $[30! + 2, 30! + 30]$

Tags: prime-numbers, factorial

How to find number of primes numbers $\pi(x)$ in $[30! + 2$ , $30! + 30]$,

where $n!$ is defined as:

$$n!= n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots3\times2\times1$$

**Using Fermat's Theorem:**
$130=1\mod31$,
(since $31 \in \mathbb{P}$). This implies the above is congruent to $17\mod31$.

This is correct, right?

Comment: As a side question,can there exist 100 consecutive integers that are all composite?

Comment: Related: (rather, almost the same) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/852598/if-n-51-1-then-find-no-of-primes-among-n1-n2-ldots-n50

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $30!$ is divisible by all numbers from $2$ to $30$ obviously,

$30!+2$ is divisible by $2$

$30!+3$ is divisible by $3$

$\vdots$

$30!+30$ is divisible by $30$

No primes.

Answer (score 3):

Observe that

$$n!+m$$ is divisible by $m$ for $2\le m\le n$ and integer $n\ge2$

So, we can have an arbitrarily large sequence of composite numbers for an arbitrary large value of integer $n$