# Elementary number theory(number of prime numbers)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n= 2016!+1$. Then the number of primes among $n+1,n+2,\ldots, n+2015 $ will be?

I am confused about how to begin solving this. Could anyone please teach me the concept I need to know to achieve this problem's answer. And also please let me know if there is any shortcut or logic behind these kind of problems.

Comment: Does $2016!+2$ have any factors that you can think of?  What about $2016!+3$?  Is there a pattern that you see here?

Comment: Not exactly, could you simplify.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/852598/if-n-51-1-then-find-number-of-primes-among-n1-n2-ldots-n50  see this

Comment: The login is to realize 2016! Is divisible by all 1 <k <= 2016 so every 2016! + k is divisible by k and is not prime.  Only 2016! +1 might be prime.  Any other 2016! + k will be divisible by k.

Answer (score 1):

Let $1\leq k\leq 2015$. Then, note that
$$
n+k=2016!+(k+1) 
$$
is divisible by $k+1$ since $k+1$ divides both $k+1$ and $2016!$, since $k+1\leq 2016$.

Answer (score 1):

The number $A = 1\times2\times3\times4\times5\times\cdots\times 2016$ is divisble by $1$ and by $2$ and by $3$ and by $4$ and by $\ldots\ldots\ldots$ and by $2016$.

Since $A$ is divisible by $7$, we conclude that $A+7$ is also divisible by $7$, and therefore is not prime. Similarly $A$ is divisible by $43$, and we conclude that $A+43$ is divisible by $43$ and is therefore not prime.

And similarly, for the same reason, every one of the numbers in your list, $A+2, A+2, A+3, \ldots, A+2016$ fails to be prime.

Answer (score 0):

Added: I had not noticed that the initial number given was already $2016! + 1.$ Therefore, the bit about Wilson's Theorem does not come into play for the range of numbers specified. Cute, though.

Critical that $2017$ is prime. [Wilson's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson's_theorem) says that $2016! + 1$ is divisible by $2017.$

However: if Ibrahimović were unable to do this problem, would he be playing for Manchester United right now? I don't think so.